# actionscript 3.0 loaded swf dimensions (width, height) remains 0

Tags: actionscript, width, flash, loader, dimension

I am loading an external swf from an external site.  After the swf has loaded and been added to the stage (I wait for the added to stage event as well), the content width/ height remain 0.  The contentLoaderInfo contains the correct width and height.  Frequently, I am unable to set the width and height.  they remain 0.

```
        imageLoader = new Loader();
        imageLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadImageComplete);
        imageLoader.load(urlRequest, context);  

    private function onLoadImageComplete(event:Event):void
    {
        removeEventListeners();
        this.mouseChildren = true;
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, addedToStageEventHandler);
        trace(imageLoader.content.height);
        trace(imageLoader.contentLoaderInfo.height)
    }

    private function addedToStageEventHandler(event:Event):void
    {
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, addedToStageEventHandler);
        trace(imageLoader.content.height);
        trace(imageLoader.contentLoaderInfo.height)
    }
```

After load complete the output is 0, 199.  After the added to stage the trace is sometimes 0, 199 sometimes 199, 199.  If the dimensions are 0 the swf never appears.  What can I do to guarantee the size.  I know nothing about the contents of the swf being loaded.

Comment: What happens if you let it load into the default context?

Comment: By default context do you mean passing null for context?  I have the same issue either way

Answer (score 0):

Wait for `Event.INIT` instead of `Event.COMPLETE` as it is fired when the item is ready for use.